# Postfix/Dovecot receiving email but nothing in mail box

Tags: linux, email, postfix, dovecot

When I send an email to myself I get the following log messages:

```
Aug 24 20:10:40 google-way postfix/trivial-rewrite[3251]: warning: do not list domain mwdesenvolvimento.com.br in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Aug 24 20:10:40 google-way postfix/cleanup[3252]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 39: overriding earlier entry: myhostname=mx.$mydomain
Aug 24 20:10:40 google-way postfix/cleanup[3252]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 42: overriding earlier entry: myorigin=$mydomain
Aug 24 20:10:40 google-way postfix/cleanup[3252]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 43: overriding earlier entry: mydestination=localhost
Aug 24 20:10:40 google-way postfix/smtpd[3249]: A09B560A1F: client=mail-it0-f53.google.com[209.85.214.53]
Aug 24 20:10:40 google-way postfix/cleanup[3252]: A09B560A1F: message-id=<CAH54gK3BMy=NWMjF3dXhqmnXBdufjS+BgQQMBj2MzviNn-ewCQ@mail.gmail.com>
Aug 24 20:10:40 google-way postfix/qmgr[3078]: A09B560A1F: from=<felipe.miquilini@gmail.com>, size=2697, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 24 20:10:40 google-way postfix/trivial-rewrite[3251]: warning: do not list domain mwdesenvolvimento.com.br in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Aug 24 20:10:40 google-way postfix/local[3253]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 39: overriding earlier entry: myhostname=mx.$mydomain
Aug 24 20:10:40 google-way postfix/smtpd[3249]: disconnect from mail-it0-f53.google.com[209.85.214.53]
Aug 24 20:10:40 google-way postfix/local[3253]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 42: overriding earlier entry: myorigin=$mydomain
Aug 24 20:10:40 google-way postfix/local[3253]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 43: overriding earlier entry: mydestination=localhost
Aug 24 20:10:40 google-way postfix/local[3253]: A09B560A1F: to=<contato@mwdesenvolvimento.com.br>, relay=local, delay=0.08, delays=0.07/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Aug 24 20:10:40 google-way postfix/qmgr[3078]: A09B560A1F: removed
```

I have read somewhere that I should try to solve this `do not list domain mwdesenvolvimento.com.br in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains`, because it may be putting my email in a different place...

Here is my `main.cf` from `Postfix`:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydomain = mwdesenvolvimento.com.br
myhostname = mx.$mydomain
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = localhost

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/root.mwdesenvolvimento.com.br.crt
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/mwdesenvolvimento.com.br.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/mwdesenvolvimento.com.br.dec.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = google-way.c.innate-temple-137823.internal
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mwdesenvolvimento.com.br, google-way.c.innate-temple-137823.internal, localhost.c.innate-temple-137823.internal, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 104.197.230.12 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
relayhost = [smtp.sendgrid.net]:2525

smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
header_size_limit = 4096000
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

# smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
# The path is relative to $queue_directory:
#   $postconf |grep queue_directory
#   queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
# Do not accept SASL authentication over unencrypted connections
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes



# Handing off local delivery to Dovecot's LMTP
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixDovecotLMTP
#
# The path relative to $queue_directory, that is:
#    /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp

# Check domains only, query users and aliases in Dovecot
#
# IMPORTANT: Don't overlap with $mydestination
#virtual_mailbox_domains = example1.com, example2.com
virtual_mailbox_domains = $mydomain

#virtual_alias_domains = $virtual_alias_maps
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_aliases
```

`dovecot.conf`:

```
# 2.2.13: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian 8.5 
# mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
# passdb {
#   driver = pam
# }
passdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  # The entire email address will be used as the username for email client.
  # Don't bother about the scheme here, will be overwritten by a strong scheme from file.
  #    (http://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/PasswdFile)
  args = scheme=CRYPT username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/users
}
protocols = " imap lmtp"

service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 0
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
  }
}

ssl = required
ssl_ca = </etc/ssl/certs/root.mwdesenvolvimento.com.br.crt
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/mwdesenvolvimento.com.br.crt
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/mwdesenvolvimento.com.br.dec.key

# userdb {
#   driver = passwd
# }
userdb {
  # For static type, LDA verify the user's existence by lookup passdb
  #   ( http://wiki2.dovecot.org/UserDatabase/Static )
  driver = static
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/vmail/%d/%n
}

# Allows plaintext authentication only when SSL/TLS is used first.
#   http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication
auth_mechanisms = plain login
disable_plaintext_auth = yes

service auth-worker {
  # Forbid to access /etc/shadow
  user = $default_internal_user
}

service auth {
  # IMPORTANT: Match the path to smtpd_sasl_path of Postfix
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    user = postfix
    mode = 0666
  }
}

service lmtp {
 unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
   mode = 0666
   user = postfix
   group = postfix
  }
}
```

Output of `ls -l /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp`: (asked by user1700494)

```
srw-rw-rw- 1 postfix postfix 0 Aug 24 19:23 /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp
```

By the way, I am neither being able to read nor send emails... Any help will be very welcomed!

Comment: show output of `ls -l /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp`

Comment: @user1700494 I changed my question to show what you asked....

Comment: My working instance is using `600` permission on `lmtp` socket. And `dovecot`'s wiki also uses `600` in its example. I'd give a try...

Comment: @user1700494 I have tried your suggestion but there is no difference...

Comment: Have you changed both socket permissions and settings in `dovecot.conf`?

Comment: It is working, I was overriding some instructions, and I forgot `virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp`